# sectionName in tableView with date

Tags: swift, tableview

```
//date 
func sectionName() -> String{
    var shortDate: String
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"


 return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
}

//tableView 
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchedRequest, managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionName", cacheName: nil)
```

//error

```
is not key value coding-compliant for the key "sectionName".'
```

I am stuck the app is crashing at "sectionName" I don't know why.

Comment: Where did you define that method? The sectionNameKeyPath must be a property of the managed object subclass that is being fetched. And what are you trying to achieve? Returning the *current date* does not make much sense.

Comment: `sectionNameKeyPath` will be used to group the data. If your `sectionNameKeyPath` is `dob` then all the people with same dob will be in one section

Answer (score 2):

You have probably defined `sectionName()` as a free function,
and not as a property or method of your managed object subclass that is being
fetched. Also formatting the "current date" as a string does
not make much sense, as you probably want to group the objects
according to some date property of your entity.

---

Apple's sample project [Custom Section Titles with NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) demonstrates how to group a table view into
sections based on the month and year of a "timeStamp" property.

That project is written in *Objective-C*.
Here is a short recipe how the same can be achieved in *Swift*.
In the following, I assume that the entity and the managed object
subclass is called `Event`, and that the events should be grouped
according to the month and year of the `timeStamp` property.

First, add a *transient* property "sectionIdentifier" of type "String"
to the "Event" entity.

Next, define the `sectionIdentifier` property of the `Event` class.
This can be done directly in the `class Event { ... }` definition
or as an extension:

```
extension Event {
    var sectionIdentifier : String? {
        // Create and cache the section identifier on demand.

        self.willAccessValueForKey("sectionIdentifier")
        var tmp = self.primitiveValueForKey("sectionIdentifier") as? String
        self.didAccessValueForKey("sectionIdentifier")

        if tmp == nil {
            if let timeStamp = self.valueForKey("timeStamp") as? NSDate {
                /*
                Sections are organized by month and year. Create the section
                identifier as a string representing the number (year * 1000) + month;
                this way they will be correctly ordered chronologically regardless
                of the actual name of the month.
                */
                let calendar  = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
                let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth, fromDate: timeStamp)
                tmp = String(format: "%ld", components.year * 1000 + components.month)
                self.setPrimitiveValue(tmp, forKey: "sectionIdentifier")
            }
        }
        return tmp
    }
}
```

In the table view controller, you have to override the 
`titleForHeaderInSection` method to compute a proper title from
the section identifier:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    /*
    * Creating a date formatter is "expensive". Use a static property so that
    * this is done only once.
    */
    struct Formatter {
        static let formatter : NSDateFormatter = {
            let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
            let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("MMMM yyyy", options: 0,
                locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())
            fmt.dateFormat = dateFormat
            return fmt
            }()
    }

    /*
    Section information derives from an event's sectionIdentifier, which is a string
    representing the number (year * 1000) + month.
    To display the section title, convert the year and month components to a string representation.
    */

    if let theSection = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] as? NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo,
        let numericSection = theSection.name?.toInt() {
            let components = NSDateComponents()
            components.year = numericSection / 1000
            components.month = numericSection % 1000
            if let date = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components) {
                let titleString = Formatter.formatter.stringFromDate(date)
                return titleString
            }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Finally, create the fetched results controller with "timeStamp"
as first sort descriptor and "sectionIdentifier" as `sectionNameKeyPath`:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Event")
let timeStampSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [timeStampSort]
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, 
        managedObjectContext: context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionIdentifier",
        cacheName: nil)
```

If the time stamp of an object can be *modified* then things become
slightly more complicated. The corresponding "sectionIdentifier"
must be invalidated so that it is computed again on demand.
In Objective-C, that is fairly simple by overriding the getter method
of the "timeStamp" property only (see [DateSectionTitles/APLEvent.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Listings/DateSectionTitles_APLEvent_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009939-DateSectionTitles_APLEvent_m-DontLinkElementID_6)). In Swift this seems
to require that you define "timeStamp" as a normal computed property (without @NSManaged), as discussed in https://devforums.apple.com/thread/262118?tstart=0:

```
class Event: NSManagedObject {

    //@NSManaged var timeStamp : NSDate
    var timeStamp: NSDate? {
        get {
            self.willAccessValueForKey("timeStamp")
            let tmp = self.primitiveValueForKey("timeStamp") as? NSDate
            self.didAccessValueForKey("timeStamp")
            return tmp
        }
        set {
            self.willChangeValueForKey("timeStamp")
            self.setPrimitiveValue(newValue, forKey: "timeStamp")
            self.didChangeValueForKey("timeStamp")
            // If the time stamp changes, the section identifier become invalid.
            self.setPrimitiveValue(nil, forKey: "sectionIdentifier")
        }
    }

    override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey(key: String) -> Set<NSObject> {
        var keyPaths = super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey(key)
        if key == "sectionIdentifier" {
            keyPaths.insert("timeStamp")
        }
        return keyPaths
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** As of **Swift 4** you have to make the custom Core Data properties explicitly visible to the Objective-C runtime by adding 
the `@objc` attribute, e.g.

```
@objc var sectionIdentifier : String? { ... }

@objc var timeStamp: NSDate? { ... }
```

For more information about this change, see

- [Swift 4 "This class is not key value coding compliant"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762460/swift-4-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant)
- [How can I deal with @objc inference deprecation with #selector() in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390378/how-can-i-deal-with-objc-inference-deprecation-with-selector-in-swift-4)

Comment: Hey @Martin-r, I followed your code and it works on iOS 10. On iOS 11, the property is not recognised and the app crashes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610890/core-data-ios11-nsunknownkeyexception-crash-in-sectionnamekeypath-with-custom

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @alpennec: I assume that you just have to add `@objc`, as I commented to your other question (which would make it a duplicate). Please let me know if that helps, then I'll update the code here. Thanks!

Comment: Adding ```objc``` before the definition of the variable fixed the issue. Thanks for your comment!