# How can I deal with @objc inference deprecation with #selector() in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I'm trying to convert my project's source code from Swift 3 to Swift 4. One warning Xcode is giving me is about my selectors.

For instance, I add a target to a button using a regular selector like this:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

This is the warning it shows:

> Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'myAction()' in 'ViewController' that depends on '@objc' attribute inference deprecated in Swift 4
>
> Add '@objc' to expose this instance method to Objective-C

Now, hitting `Fix` on the error message does this to my function:

```
// before
func myAction() { /* ... */ }

// after
@objc func myAction() { /* ... */ }
```

I don't really want to rename all of my functions to include the `@objc` mark and I'm assuming that's not necessary.

How do I rewrite the selector to deal with the deprecation?

---

**Related question:**

- [The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379348/the-use-of-swift-3-objc-inference-in-swift-4-mode-is-deprecated)

Comment: Nope, marking them as `@objc` *is* now necessary in order to expose them to Obj-C, and therefore use with selectors.

Comment: So the deprecated part is inferring public-access functions as `@objc`? That is a bit annoying, but I generally make these functions private, requiring me to mark it as `@objc` anyways.

Comment: See [SE-0160](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md) for more info about the change. Another alternative is marking your given class as `@objcMembers` in order to expose all Obj-C compatible members to Obj-C, but I wouldn't advise that unless you actually need your entire class to be exposed.

Comment: What would be the consequence of that, @Hamish? It seems more convenient to set the whole class to `@objc` than doing that for each function individually.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth As said in the proposal, it would likely unnecessarily increase the size of your binary and dynamic linking would take longer. I really don't think it's too much hassle for the added clarity that you specifically mean for a particular thing to be used from Obj-C.

Comment: So wrapping up: only solution would be to mark each individual function (requiring it) with `@objc`. If so, post that as an answer and I'll accept it. @Hamish. Thanks for your help!

Comment: try this `#selector(ViewController.myAction)`

Comment: Tried, not working.

Comment: Related question which gets to the core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379348/the-use-of-swift-3-objc-inference-in-swift-4-mode-is-deprecated?rq=1

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The fix-it is correct – there's nothing about the selector you can change in order to make the method it refers to exposed to Objective-C.

The whole reason for this warning in the first place is the result of [SE-0160](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md). Prior to Swift 4, `internal` or higher Objective-C compatible members of `NSObject` inheriting classes were inferred to be `@objc` and therefore exposed to Objective-C, therefore allowing them to be called using selectors (as the Obj-C runtime is required in order to lookup the method implementation for a given selector).

However in Swift 4, this is no longer the case. Only very specific declarations are now inferred to be `@objc`, for example, overrides of `@objc` methods, implementations of `@objc` protocol requirements and declarations with attributes that imply `@objc`, such as `@IBOutlet`.

The motivation behind this, as detailed [in the above linked proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md), is firstly to prevent method overloads in `NSObject` inheriting classes from colliding with each other due to having identical selectors. Secondly, it helps reduce the binary size by not having to generate thunks for members that don't need to be exposed to Obj-C, and thirdly improves the speed of dynamic linking.

If you want to expose a member to Obj-C, you need to mark it as `@objc`, for example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(foo), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func foo() {
       // ... 
    }
}
```

*(the migrator should do this automatically for you with selectors when running with the "minimise inference" option selected)*

To expose a group of members to Obj-C, you can use an `@objc extension`:

```
@objc extension ViewController {

    // both exposed to Obj-C
    func foo() {}
    func bar() {}
}
```

This will expose all the members defined in it to Obj-C, and give an error on any members that cannot be exposed to Obj-C (unless explicitly marked as `@nonobjc`).

If you have a class where you need *all* Obj-C compatible members to be exposed to Obj-C, you can mark the class as `@objcMembers`:

```
@objcMembers
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   // ...
}
```

Now, all members that can be inferred to be `@objc` will be. However, I wouldn't advise doing this unless you *really* need all members exposed to Obj-C, given the above mentioned downsides of having members unnecessarily exposed.

Comment: Why does Xcode not automatically do that when converting the code to the latest syntax?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Hmm, it does for me – when going Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax... and going through the migrator (with "minimise inference" selected), any selectors that refer to methods that aren't `@objc` get made `@objc`. Maybe try running the migrator again?

Comment: Right, I should've tried that. Did it manually now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I wonder, are `@IBAction` also automatically `@objc`? that was not the case until now but it would be logical. EDIT: nvm, the proposal clearly states that `@IBAction` is enough for a method to be `@objc`.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes they are – this also appears to have been the case in Swift 3.1 as well.

Comment: @Hamish I think that explicit `@objc` was required for `private` actions.

Comment: @Sulthan Hmm, no still working fine with `@IBAction private` in Swift 3.1

Comment: @Hamish You are right, there had to be a change I missed.

Comment: I don't understand any of this. I have no Objective-C-code what so ever. Is there no pure Swift-way of adding targets to a button? Or use selectors? I don't want my code to be riddled with this attribute. Is it because a UIButton is derived from some NSObject/Obj-c-thing?

Comment: @Sti Target-selector is an Obj-C pattern, and relies on the Obj-C runtime to work. You may not *directly* have any Obj-C code in your project, but under the hood on Apple platforms, Swift classes are built on Obj-C classes. They are therefore exposed to the Obj-C runtime (although members of the class aren't exposed by default – marking them as `@objc` does so). On other platforms, such as Linux, there is *no* Obj-C runtime, so you cannot, for example, use the `#selector` directive (you could consider this "pure Swift")...

Comment: ... As said in my answer, by inheriting from `NSObject` (which brings a bunch of convenience methods for interacting with the Obj-C runtime), Swift used to assume that you wanted *all* (`internal` or higher) Obj-C compatible members of your class to be exposed to Obj-C by default. This is no longer the case – you have to specify which members to expose (or use `@objcMembers` to expose all again).

Comment: @Sti So to directly answer "*Is there no pure Swift-way of adding targets to a button? Or use selectors?*" – no, there is no "pure Swift" way of using selectors to dispatch to methods. They rely on the Obj-C runtime in order to lookup the method implementation to call for a particular selector – the Swift runtime doesn't have that capability.

Comment: @Hamish: Thanks a lot for the explanation. My problem -> After following the "fix" and got the additional *@obj* in front of my method, another warning comes up. I use Xcode version 9.0 beta 2 (9M137d). The warning is "The use of Swift 3 *@objc* inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated *@objc* inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 *@objc* inference” logging enabled, and disable Swift 3 *@objc* inference."

Comment: Man selectors are a mess. It seems like every other swift update they are messing with it. Why can't we just have a pure swift autocomplete selector for methods. Makes code look so ugly.

Answer (score 16):

**As [Apple Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID59). you need to use @objc to call your Selector Method.**

> In Objective-C, a selector is a type that refers to the name of an
>   Objective-C method. In Swift, Objective-C selectors are represented by
>   the `Selector` structure, and can be constructed using the `#selector`
>   expression. To create a selector for a method that can be called from
>   Objective-C, pass the name of the method, such as
>   `#selector(MyViewController.tappedButton(sender:))`. To construct a selector for a property’s Objective-C getter or setter method, pass
>   the property name prefixed by the `getter:` or `setter:` label, such as
>   `#selector(getter: MyViewController.myButton)`.

Comment: all I understand from this is that in some cases I need to add @objc to the start of a func whether or not I'm ever going to call it from Objective-C. I'm just learning Swift having used Obj-C for years

Answer (score 11):

As of, I think Swift 4.2, all you need to do is assign `@IBAction` to your method and avoid the `@objc` annotation.

```
let tap  =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.cancel))

@IBAction func cancel()
{
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This will also tell interface builder that this function can be connected, which might not be what you want. It's also doing the same thing as @objc.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in other answers, there is no way to avoid the `@objc` annotation for selectors.

But warning mentioned in the OP can be silenced by taking following steps:

1. Go to **Build Settings**
2. Search for keyword **@objc**
3. Set the value of **Swift 3 @objc interface** to `Off`

below is the screenshot that illustrates the above mentioned steps:

[image: Silencing the warning "Swift 3 @objc interface"]

Hope this helps

Comment: How does this affect your project in the bigger picture?

Comment: How about *.ipa or *.xarchive size, and build time?

Comment: @ZonilyJame i didn't notice the build time, but there was no effect on IPA size

Comment: This is not recommanded value you can use if you use swift 4.0+ version as per the Apple guidelines. Check this https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deve838b19a1

Comment: @Bhavin_m there isn't mentioned about this being a non-recommended approach in the link you shared.

Comment: You can update this answer by setting the value to Default in Xcode 11. It's important to set the value on both the project and your targets to remove the warning fully.

Answer (score 2):

If you need objective c members in your view controller just add  ***@objcMembers*** at the top of the view controller. And you can avoid this by adding IBAction in your code.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction() {

}
```

Make sure to connect this outlet in storyboard.