# value(forKey:) for NSObject not working in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

Trying out Swift 4 in Xcode 9 Beta.

For some reason I'm getting a crash when using key value accessors on an NSObject.

Any ideas?

```
import Cocoa

class Person: NSObject {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
}

let alpha = Person()
alpha.name = "Robert"
alpha.age = 53

alpha.value(forKey: "name")
// error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

Comment: Related: [How can I deal with @objc inference deprecation with #selector() in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/2976878)

Comment: If you call `value(forKey:)` with  `#keyPath(Person.name)` instead of a string then the compiler will show a proper error message and Fix-it!

Comment: Or even, now that you're in Swift 4, use Swift's key-value coding mechanism `print(alpha[keyPath: \Person.name])` :) Then you don't have to inherit from `NSObject` and can even make `Person` a `struct`.

Comment: I'm using key-value coding in order to dynamically select the property to access from a string variable. Is there any way to do this using the new Swift 4 mechanism?

Comment: @closetCoder You can store and pass about key paths, e.g `let name = \Person.name`, but they're not strings (they're strongly typed instead). Strings are such weak types to represent key-paths, and should really be avoided unless absolutely necessary. What's your use case for using a string key path?

Comment: Data source for an NSTableView. I use the identifier of the column to select which property to return as the value.

Comment: @closetCoder When and where do the identifiers get set? I don't have much experience with `NSTableView`, but how about just having your data source hold an array of `PartialKeyPath<Person>` (key paths that start at `Person`, but can go to any sub-property in the object graph), with each corresponding to the property to display for a given column index? Then just subscript your model with the key path for a given column index.

Comment: @Hamish The identifiers are set in Interface Builder. It is not a problem to use a switch statement. It just seems a bit inelegant to do stuff like case "name": return data.name case "age": return data.age etc.

Comment: @closetCoder Oh I agree (you wouldn't have to switch with the strongly-typed key-paths either) – but the problem with using strings as key paths is that they're really error-prone (e.g typos, rename/remove a model property without changing the key-path) as well as the fact that they don't carry any type information, so the compiler cannot enforce you're using them correctly (e.g using them on the correct type of object).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Key-value coding requires Objective-C. In Swift 4 you have to mark members accessible from Obj-C explicitly:

```
@objcMembers
class Person: NSObject {
```

or

```
class Person: NSObject {
    @objc var name = ""
    var age = 0
}
```

See [Swift Evolution 160](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md)

Answer (score 7):

ObjC inference has been [limited](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md) in Swift 4. You can mark your class with `objcMembers` for the compiler to generate ObjC-compliant accessors:

```
@objcMembers
class Person: NSObject {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
}
```

Or get back the old behavior by setting **Swift 3 Objc Inference** to On in Build Settings:

[image]

Comment: Note that the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting is only really there to assist with the migration, and therefore isn't a permanent solution.