# Selector vs Action Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, selector, swift4

New to Swift. I have two snippets below:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
    selector:#selector(ViewController.notificationReceived), 
    name: Notification.Name(rawValue: name), object: nil)

@objc func notificationReceived(notification:Notification){
    let x = notification.userInfo!
    print("\(x["name"]!)")

}
```

and finally

```
let x:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
    action: #selector(tapped))

self.addGestureRecognizer(x)

func tapped(){
    print("tapped")

    self.delegate!.theViewTapped()

}
```

Why is it that for the `notificationCenter`? I am supposed to provide the `@objc` tag for the `selector` parameter but not for the `UITapGestureRecognizer` action parameter?

What exactly is the difference between `Selector` and `Action in` Swift?

Comment: Compare [How can I deal with @objc inference deprecation with #selector() in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/2976878) – as OOPer says, both examples require the target method to be `@objc`.

Answer (score 10):

Check this proposal for Swift 4:
[SE-0160 Limiting @objc inference](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md)

According to the description in the proposal, your second code snippet also needs `@objc`.

In fact, Swift 4 compiler bundled with Xcode 9 beta2 generates this error for the line using `#selector(tapped)`:

> error: argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'tapped()'
>   that is not exposed to Objective-C
>
> note: add '@objc' to expose this instance method to Objective-C

Maybe your second is a little bit too old to use with Swift 4. You better think ***all methods invoked through selector need `@objc` attribute.***