# Unable to access Swift 4 class from Objective-C: "Property not found on object of type"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift4

Using the latest Xcode 9 beta, I'm seemingly completely unable to access properties on Swift classes. Even odder, I can access the class itself to instantiate it or whatever, but completely unable to access properties on it.

So if I have this Swift class:

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    var foobar = true
}
```

And I try to do this:

```
TestViewController *testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init]; // success
testViewController.foobar; // error
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? New project with Xcode 9.

Comment: Compare [How can I deal with @objc inference deprecation with #selector() in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/2976878)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

The rules for exposing Swift code to Objective-C have changed in Swift 4. Try this instead:

```
@objc var foobar = true
```

As an optimization, `@objc` inference have been reduced in Swift 4. For instance, a property within an `NSObject`-derived class, such as your `TestViewController`, will *no* longer infer `@objc` by default (as it did in Swift 3).

Alternatively, you could also expose *all* members to Objective-C at once using `@objcMembers`:

```
@objcMembers class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}
```

This new design is fully detailed in [the corresponding Swift Evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md).

Comment: I am still facing issue to access  Int & Bool properties from Swift to objective-C ... and getting this error : **Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C** , Any suggetion ? .. I have used header "MyProject-Swift.h

Comment: **Only String Properties are accessible**

Comment: Stupid upgrade. Now I have to add @objc pre-processor on every variable and method declaration if using it on Objective C class

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed I can access Booleans as well.

Comment: The alternate didn't work for me. I had to prefix @objc to the class and all it's member fields

Comment: Very interesting. I have it working with both versions.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! This has been driving me nuts all morning, but your post clarified several points and gave the solution in the form of @objcMembers that works perfectly in my case, which is a class with a variety of String, Int, Float and CLLocationDegrees properties.

Answer (score 15):

Swift 3.2/4.0 / XCode 9.1

You you set swift3.2 in project settings ( *//:configuration = Debug
SWIFT_VERSION = 3.2* )

you can use your code,(using the correct import file in objc, see below).
If You set project to swift 4.0 ( *//:configuration = Debug
SWIFT_VERSION = 4.0* )

You must prepend @objc for every property.

So:

**Swift 3.2:**

```
// MyClass.swift

@objc class MyClass: NSObject{

    var s1: String?
    @objc var s2 : String?
}


//

//  ViewController.m

import "MixingObjCAndSwift-Swift.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    MyClass * mc = [MyClass new];
    NSString * s1 = mc.s1;
    NSString * s2 = mc.s2;
}
```

works.

**Swift 4.0:**

```
// MyClass.swift

@objc class MyClass: NSObject{

    var s1: String?
    @objc var s2 : String?
}


.....  
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    MyClass * mc = [MyClass new];
    NSString * s1 = mc.s1;
    NSString * s2 = mc.s2;
}
```

does NOT works: compiler fails:

/Users....ViewController.m:24:21: Property 's1' not found on object of type 'MyClass *'

as s1 is not prepended with @objc.

You must write:

```
@objc class MyClass: NSObject{

    @objc var s1: String?
    @objc var s2 : String?
}
```

(As a side-note: in C/C++/ObJC file, put always system/general *h files before your "local" class headers.)

**Swift 4**

just add @objcMembers before class
**@objcMembers** class MyClassObject: NSObject
{
    var s1: String!
    var s2: String!

}
Swift evolution[enter link description here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution)

Answer (score 13):

As for Swift 5.1 I found that "@objc" is not enough, but also make it public "@objc public":

```
@objc public class SomeClass: NSObject {
    @objc public let amount: NSNumber
...
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me for String? property with explicit `set` and `get` blocks. Anybody faced this as well?

Comment: @Dan I believe optional is a Struct, this means that it can't be exposured to Obj-C runtime

Answer (score 3):

1. When you add a swift file in your Objective-C project, Xcode will prompt to add *Objective-C bridging header* file, so allow the header file to be created.
2. In your Objective-C implementation file where you want to access the TestViewController property *foobar*. Use the following import syntax and replace the ProjectName with your project.

> #import "ProjectName-Swift.h"

**Objective-C implementation file:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    TestViewController *testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init]; // success
    BOOL prop = testViewController.foobar;
    NSLog(@"Property: %d", prop);
}

@end
```

For more details go through the [Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode 10.2 | Swift 4** 
Adding `@objcMembers` before class solved my problem.

```
@objcMembers class MyClass:NSObject {
   var s1: String!
   var s2: NSMutableArray!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered with this problem in swift 3.0

class declaration was like that

```
class ClassA {
//statements
}
```

above class was not accessible in Objective C code and it was also not registered in -Swift.h

once I inherited from NSObject like this:

```
class ClassA : NSObject {
//statements
}
```

the class was accessible in Objective c and got registered with -Swift.h

This solution is useful when you don't want to avoid inheritance from NSobject class.