# @objc at class level not working. Have to manually mark all property as @objc to use in objective c class

Tags: objective-c, swift

Even If I am marking any swift class @objc, not able to use any of its property in objectiveC class. I have to mark all property as @objc. Is there any way ,I dont want to mark all property @objc manually,That is too much work.

Comment: You need `@objcMembers` at the class level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access Swift 4 class from Objective-C: "Property not found on object of type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656671/unable-to-access-swift-4-class-from-objective-c-property-not-found-on-object-o)

Comment: data that you need to access in objective c should be @objc predifined in swift