# Upgrading Swift 3 to 4, swift extension no longer in objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, extension-methods, swift4

I just finished upgrading a mixed language project (objective-c and Swift) from Swift 3 to Swift 4.

Everything seemed to go well except all of my Swift extensions are no longer accessible in objective-c.  I can't figure out how to get *any* Swift extension to show up in objective-c.  I've tried searching, but I can't find any mention of changes to extensions in Swift 4 except for loosening up the `private` scope.

- All of these extensions were accessible from Objective-c in Swift 3, so there are no incompatible types (structs or non-raw enums).
- The extensions are marked public.
- The extensions are part of the same target and in the same project as the objective-c files.
- Yes, I have imported "ProjectName-Swift.h" in the relevant objective-c files.
- Other compatible Swift classes *do* show up.  It seems just the extensions are missing.
- I've tried marking each `func` public as well.

For example, the following extension used to be available to objective-c code when I was using Swift 3:

```
public extension UIAlertController {

  class func alert(_ title: String? = nil, message: String? = nil) -> UIAlertController {
    return UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
  }

  @discardableResult func action(_ action: String) -> UIAlertController {
    self.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: action, style: .default, handler: nil))
    return self
  }

  @discardableResult func action(_ action: String, style: UIAlertActionStyle = .default, onSelected: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil) -> UIAlertController {
    self.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: action, style: style, handler: onSelected))
    return self
  }

  @discardableResult func cancel(_ action: String? = "Cancel", onCancel: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil) -> UIAlertController {
    self.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: action, style: .cancel, handler: { alert in
      onCancel?(alert)
    }))
    return self
  }

  @discardableResult func destructive(_ action: String, onDestruct: @escaping ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)) -> UIAlertController {
    self.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: action, style: .destructive, handler: { action in
      onDestruct(action)
    }))
    return self
  }

  func presentOn(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool = true) {
    viewController.present(self, animated: animated, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably have to add `@objc` to all methods.

Comment: Or just the extension declaration itself, e.g `@objc public extension` (compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/2976878)

Comment: Ah, yep... that was it.  I guess that's related to the `@objc` inference changes they made.

Comment: Anyone want to add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A super simple solution is to just add `@objc public extension` to the declaration of each Swift extension.