# "class_copyMethodList" returning only init method

Tags: swift4

I am trying to get method list of a class. Here's my code

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
  func method1(){
    print("Method1")
  }

  func method2(){
    print("Method2")
  }
}

var methodCount: UInt32 = 0
let methodList = class_copyMethodList(MyClass.self, &methodCount)

for i in 0..<Int(methodCount){
   let unwrapped = methodList?[i]
   print(NSStringFromSelector(method_getName(unwrapped!)))
}
```

Output is :

```
init
```

`method1` and `method2` are not displaying in output.

Please correct me if i am doing something wrong. Help will be appriciated.

Thank You

Comment: Are you using Swift 4? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390378/how-can-i-deal-with-objc-inference-deprecation-with-selector-in-swift-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expose your methods to Objective C with the @objc attribute.

Like this:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
  @objc func method1(){
    print("Method1")
  }

  @objc func method2(){
    print("Method2")
  }
}
```