# Swift4: respondstoSelector not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsobject, swift4

Following code works perfectly in swift 3.x but not in swift 4.

```
let selector = "managerDidDetectedStation:"
let observer = <UIViewController subclass object>
let station = <Station Object>

if observer.responds(to: Selector(selector) {         
    observer.perform(Selector(selector), with: station)
}
```

`observer.responds(to: Selector(selector)` always returns false. Does anybody aware of any change in this api in swift4?

Comment: UIViewController does not have managerDidDetectedStation method, does it?

Comment: It does. func managerDidDetectedStation(_ station : Station) { }

Comment: Is this a method you've added in Swift but haven't annotated as `@objc`? See this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/2976878. But you should really use `#selector` here; the compiler can catch these mistakes for you.

Comment: @AbidHussain hmm. Can you provide a reference for this method? I'm curious to see the docs. UIViewController class reference does not mention this method

Comment: Also why are you using `responds(to:)` + `perform(_:with:)`? Is this genuinely a method that you're dynamically adding at runtime, or is this just an optional protocol requirement? If it's the latter, Swift makes the method (on the protocol type) an optional, you can just use optional chaining with it.

Comment: Hamish it's the baggage I got from another developer. I'm converting his project to Swift4. The requirement was to have 1-N communication and that's why MonitoringManger singleton has an array of observers which all get notified through this method.

Comment: @AbidHussain Ah okay; you're quite correct that it needs a redesign :) For simple cases, you may want to consider just storing an array of closures.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add **@objcMembers** at top of `observer` class

For Ex. if `observer` is a object of `XYZClass` class then write

```
@objcMembers
class XYZClass : NSObject
{
  // Your Stuff
}
```

**OR**

Another way is to put `@objc` to start of your method like below.

```
 @objc func managerDidDetectedStation...
```

Comment: Unless you really need *all* Obj-C compatible members exposed, I wouldn't advise `@objcMembers`.

Comment: thanks iPatel. I guess I need to implement proper delegation instead of this dumbass solution.

Comment: Quick note with Xcode 10: I had to use `@objcMembers`, not `@objMembers`. I'm new to Swift, so I'm not sure if that's a typo in the answer or a recent adjustment to the language (which seems to change faster than a teenager's fashion taste).