# Swift 4 - Notification Center addObserver issue

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, xcode9, addobserver

I'm crashing and getting an `unrecognized selector` error every time a `Notification` arrives and the App tries to execute its associated method.
Here's my code - which is in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("sayHello")), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "dataDownloadCompleted"), object: nil)
```

The `sayHello()` method is quite simple - looks like this:

```
func sayHello() {
    print("Hello")
}
```

I've verified that the `Notification` is posted successfully and that it *arrives* successfully - so that's not the issue. The crash happens when the App looks to act upon the arrival of the `Notification` - by executing the `sayHello()` method. It keeps giving me that `unrecognized selector` error.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  (By the way, this worked perfectly with Swift 3 & Xcode 8, but now with Swift 4 and Xcode 9 the syntax has changed [Xcode walked me through the necessary code fixes/updates] - but the crashes keep happening.)

Comment: If you had used `#selector`, the compiler would've pointed out the problem – `sayHello` needs to be `@objc`. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/2976878

Comment: Use like this `#selector(yourVC.yourfunctionName)`

Comment: As already mentioned by @Hamish you should use `#selector(sayHello)`  and your method signature you should also pass the notification object (drop the NS prefix)  `@objc func sayHello(_ notification:  Notification)`

Comment: @Mannopson no need to pass the view controller prefix. btw It should always start with an uppercase letter

Comment: @LeoDabus I always use the `self` instead of `viewControllerName`. Example: `#selector(self.functionName)`

Comment: self it is totally unnecessary. btw you mean ViewControllerName not its instance

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can improve your code with these steps:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let dataDownloadCompleted = Notification.Name(
       rawValue: "dataDownloadCompleted")
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                               selector: #selector(YourClass.sayHello),
                               name: .dataDownloadCompleted,
                               object: nil)
```

But as was already pointed out, issue is solved by changing to **#selector**

Comment: Name is not member of Notification - issue is coming in swift 4

Answer (score 10):

```
Data Receiving - Add observer:

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourfunction(notfication:)), name: .postNotifi, object: nil)
}

@objc func yourfunction(notfication: NSNotification) {
     print("xxx")
}

Sending Data - Post Notification:

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .postNotifi, object: nil)
}

extension Notification.Name {
      static let postNotifi = Notification.Name("postNotifi")
}
```

Comment: if you do your code this way, the observer is removed when the view disappears (e.g. when another view is pushed onto navigation stack), but if that new view is popped back to the original view (where the observer used to live), there's no notification observer.  Better to put `addObserver` in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.0 & Xcode 9.0+:**

Send(Post) Notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

OR

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil, userInfo: ["Renish":"Dadhaniya"])
```

Receive(Get) Notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

Function-Method handler for received Notification:

```
@objc func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification) {}
```

**Swift 3.0 & Xcode 8.0+:**

Send(Post) Notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

Receive(Get) Notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

Method handler for received Notification:

```
func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification) {
  // Take Action on Notification
}
```

Remove Notification:

```
deinit {
  NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
}
```

**Swift 2.3 & Xcode 7:**

Send(Post) Notification

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

Receive(Get) Notification

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.methodOfReceivedNotification(_:)), name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

Method handler for received Notification

```
func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: NSNotification){
  // Take Action on Notification
}
```

Ref:https://medium.com/@javedmultani16/notification-in-swift-4-8b0db631f49d