# UIControl.appearance().addTarget stopped working on Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

I have code that stopped working when I switched from Swift 3.2 to Swift 4.0. It's goal is to add click action to all UIButtons and UISwitches.

```swift
private func turnSound(state: Bool) {
    UIButton.appearance().isSoundEnabled = state
    UISwitch.appearance().isSoundEnabled = state
}
```

```swift
extension UIControl {
   var isSoundEnabled: Bool {
        get {
            return target(forAction: #selector(AudioManager.playStandardClickSound), withSender: nil) != nil ? true : false
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                addTarget(AudioManager.manager, action: #selector(AudioManager.playStandardClickSound), for: .touchUpInside)
            } else {
                removeTarget(AudioManager.manager, action: #selector(AudioManager.playStandardClickSound), for: .touchUpInside)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It worked well before, but now I'm getting an exception:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Illegal axis type, : for appearance setter, addTarget:action:forControlEvents:. Expected NSInteger or NSUInteger'
```

And I don't understand how to get rid of this problem.

Will be glad to any help or alternative solution.

**UPDATE:**

- [added sample project](https://github.com/Kirow/AppearanceTargetIssue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@objc` to your extension too:

```
@objc extension UIControl
```

P.S. Credits goes to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391389/2241008

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot!