# xcode 9.0.1 / swift 4, No method declared with Objective-C selector 'onClick:forEvent:'

Tags: swift, swift4

I use `swift 4` to build my UI，I create a `UIButton` and want to add a target to it.

But the complier throw an warning: `No method declared with Objective-C selector 'onClick:forEvent:'`

```
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("onClick:forEvent:"), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside) 
//...

func onClick(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
  print("button click", sender, event);
}
```

When I click the warning triangle try to fix this. 
`Wrap the selector name in parentheses to suppress this warning`.

It just wrap the selector name in parentheses.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("onClick:forEvent:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

build success, but when I click the button.

throw an error

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

I know it can be changed to `#selector(ViewClass.methodName)` and `@objc func methodName() {..}` way.

but why `Selector` not working ? Is this a correct `swift 4` way?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/2976878 (dupe?). You need to expose `onClick(_:forEvent:)` to Obj-C regardless of whether you use `Selector`'s initialiser or `#selector` (the latter is preferable though). Target action is an Obj-C pattern; the Obj-C runtime is needed in order to lookup the implementation to call for a given selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should prefix the function with `@objc` to make it visible to the Objective-C runtime, e.g.:

```
@objc func onClick(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent)
```

Comment: Also add selector in the following form:
`#selector(onClick(sender:event:))`

Comment: thank you very much you really save my day after 2 hours of search for nothing , thank you very much

Comment: textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector (self.textChanged), for: .editingChanged), this worked for me