# Swift method not visible in objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, compiler-errors, swift4

I have project using Swift 3.2 and Objective-C compiling with Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235).  It compiles fine in Swift 3.2.  However, when I switch to Swift 4.0, the methods declared in Swift is no longer visible in Objective-C.  The error is `No visible @interface "UserAPI" declares the selector ...`

[image][image]

Comment: Most probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829032/xcode-9-0-1-swift-4-no-method-declared-with-objective-c-selector-onclickfor and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390378/how-can-i-deal-with-objc-inference-deprecation-with-selector-in-swift-4 – add `@objc` to the members that you want to expose to Objective-C.

Answer (score 8):

You should add @objc before your function like this.

```
@objc func doSomething() {
   //Some code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or! Use @objcMembers if you'd like to expose the entire class to Objective-C

```
@objcMembers class MyClass {

    func methodOne() {
        // no @objc required!
    }

    func methodTwo() {
        // no @objc required here either!
    }

}
```