# What is the Swift 4 equivalent to the method .changeScale(byReactingTo:)

Tags: swift, swift4

```
let handler = #selector(FaceView.changeScale(byReactingTo:))
```

Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'changeScale(byReactingTo:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deal with @objc inference deprecation with #selector() in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390378/how-can-i-deal-with-objc-inference-deprecation-with-selector-in-swift-4)

Comment: This is not the same issue. The method, changeScale(byReactingTo:) has been crossed out in the intellisense.

Comment: From which pod/framework this `FaceView` class is coming from?

Comment: @DroidGuy You need to show us more context then; what defines the method `changeScale(byReactingTo:)`, and can you edit it? If not, you probably just want to use an `@objc` thunk that then forwards onto `changeScale(byReactingTo:)`.

Comment: Sorry about not being more detailed. FaceView is simply a UIView Cocoa Touch Class.