# iOS - Can't access Swift Singleton from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, singleton, swift4

I can't access my **Swift Singleton Class** from my **Objective-C** ViewController.

Xcode does recognize my Swift Class, it builds, so I don't think it is a bridging header issue.

Here is my Swift Singleton Class :

```
@objc class MySingleton : NSObject {

    static let shared = MySingleton()

    private override init() {}
}
```

And then in my **.m** file I import this header :

```
#import "myProject-Swift.h"
```

And use the Singleton this way :

```
 MySingleton *testSingleton = [MySingleton shared];
```

or this way :

```
[MySingleton shared];
```

It does recognize the MySingleton class type, but I can't access any functions or properties of this class.

What am I missing? All the similar posts didn't help.

**EDIT:** I made a test function

```
func testPrint() {
   print("Singleton worked")
}
```

And called it this way in the objective-c file :

```
[[MySingleton shared] testPrint];
```

> No known instance for selector 'testPrint'

Comment: MySingleton *testSingleton = [MySingleton shared]; by using this you are going to create another Instance while you had already Singleton.

i guess you can directlly access any methods or properties by this : [[MySingleton shared] anyMethod];

Comment: I have edited my question with an example

Comment: @GOPALVASANI you are not correct, it is a basic way of creation of singleton in swift.

Comment: @Luzo .  what is wrong with my suggestion ?  i mean develper had already shared Instance then what the need of creating another one ?

Comment: @Balanced , can you please provide me your tried code.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/2976878

Comment: Great stuff @Hamish. Good to know about this. Will definitely be helpful for the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your Swift Singleton class, add `@objc` for the method `testPrint()` like:

```
@objc func testPrint() {
   print("Singleton worked")
}
```

Now, you access the method from Objective-C class:

```
[[MySingleton shared] testPrint];
```

Comment: Ok you are correct. But I also had to add @objc to the shared property. Seems weird. I thought doing it for the whole class would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

use `@objc` attribute before the `testPrint()` function. refer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

> To be accessible and usable in Objective-C, a Swift class must be a descendant of an Objective-C class or it must be marked @objc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @objc to any property or function you want to expose to Objective-C, including the static shared property:

```
class MySingleton : NSObject {

    @objc static let shared = MySingleton()
    private override init() { }
    @objc func testPrint() { print("Singleton worked") }

}
```

Then, the call from Objective-C file:

```
MySingleton *singleton = [MySingleton shared];
[singleton testPrint];
```

Note that marking the whole class as @objc isn't a replacement for the above. It is actually not needed anymore, and it's enough to inherit from NSObject.