# NSFetchedResultsController object giving counts of entities

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a Core data with one entity named 'Cigarette' having a 'time' attribute. In my table View I have to populate each cell with total number of cigarettes for each day. How can this be done with NSFetchedResultsController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple have a sample app which demonstrates how to get an FRC to group items by date.  Sadly it's an old app written in Objective-C, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49221341/3985749) shows broadly how to implement it in Swift.

You also need to modify the standard FRC tableView datasource methods and the FRC's own delegate methods, because rather than wanting a cell for each item, you want a cell for each "group" (ie. date).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gave me some idea to start :)

Answer (score 0):

To get entities for a particular day you have to use NSPredicate to get desire date entities and apply this Predicate to NSFetchRequest, you will get that date entities only

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question so that it gives clear picture

Comment: @MohamedWasiq can you post the fetch request (Code) with question so i can post exact solution (code )

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data using `fetchedResultsController`:

**obj-c**

```
NSArray *fetchedData = [_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

**Swift**

```
guard let quotes = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects else { return 0 }
```

if you have more than 1 entity build a fetchrequest for each entity. Something like this should give you all your objects.

**Obj-c**

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

**Swift**

```
var request = NSFetchRequest()
var entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: managedObjectContext)
request.entity = entity
var error: Error?
var results = try? managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question so that it gives clear picture.