# Why do I have to create a function in Swift with @objc?

Tags: ios, swift

I am a development novice and I am currently learning Swift 4. I am writing an egg timer app and I am confused. I have created a function to decrease the time within the `scheduledTimer`. However, it will not let me compile and build until I create the `decreaseTimer()` function with @objc.

Why is this? I am confused lol. My code is working but just want to know how ?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var timer = Timer()

var time = 210

@objc func decreaseTimer() {

    if time > 0 {

    time -= 1

    timerLabel.text = String(time)
    } else {

        timer.invalidate()
    }

}


@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.decreaseTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Any advice would be most appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deal with @objc inference deprecation with #selector() in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390378/how-can-i-deal-with-objc-inference-deprecation-with-selector-in-swift-4)

Comment: Please read [SE-0160 Limiting @objc inference](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selector` is essentially a name of function that is dynamically searched on the `target` object. The problem is that Swift does not provide any reflection API to search for methods by name and then call then dynamically, that can be done only in Objective-C. Therefore, you have to make the method accessible from Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That does make sense. However, I have seen similar code run and work in Swift 3 without using @objc. Has something changed since version 3?

Comment: @Jay Yes, In Swift 3 all `NSObject` subclasses had methods that were `@objc` automatically, including all `UIViewController` and similar.

Comment: Ah okay, that explains it. I just read SE-0160 and although I don't understand all of it, I understand enough :). Thanks again Sulthan.