# class_copyPropertyList not working in Swift 5. Whats the reason?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, mirror

class_copyPropertyList is giving empty properties in Swift 5 and it was working correct in Swift 3

```
 extension NSObject {

      func toDictionary(from classType: NSObject.Type) -> [String: Any] {

          var propertiesCount : CUnsignedInt = 0
          let propertiesInAClass = class_copyPropertyList(classType, &propertiesCount)
          let propertiesDictionary : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

          for i in 0 ..< Int(propertiesCount) {
              let property = propertiesInAClass?[i]
              let strKey = NSString(utf8String: property_getName(property)) as String?
              if let key = strKey {
                  propertiesDictionary.setValue(self.value(forKey: key), forKey: key)
              }
          }
          return propertiesDictionary as! [String : Any]
      }
    }
```

// call this for NSObject subclass

```
    let product = Product()
    let dict = product.toDictionary(from: Product.self)
    print(dict)
```

Comment: Probably due to [NSObject `@objc` inference deprecation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md). You'll want to mark the stored properties as `@objc`, or if you want all members (including methods) exposed to Obj-C, mark the class as `@objcMembers`. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/2976878

Comment: Unrelated, but there's no need to pass in the `classType` parameter, you can use `type(of: self)` instead. Also note that you need to call `free(propertiesInAClass)` before the end of the method to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: how can we get property list by using type of

Comment: `class_copyPropertyList(type(of: self), &propertiesCount)`

Comment: po class_copyPropertyList(type(of: User.self), &count)
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: if self refers to object then also it is crashing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190719/discussion-between-aditya-sharma-and-hamish).