# Swift 4 "This class is not key value coding compliant"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have a Swift library which is heavily reliant on `obj.valueForKey()` from `NSObject`.

After migrating to Swift 4 I've found that these calls always crash with the error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key..." unless the property I'm looking for is declared with `@objc`.

Is it now mandatory to declare properties with `@objc` for them to be found with this method? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Compare [How can I deal with @objc inference deprecation with #selector() in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/2976878)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When you performed the migration Xcode asked about `@objc` inference and you probably selected the new type instead of Swift3.

Possible solutions:

## Use `@objc`

Use `@objc` on each method, as needed instead of the whole class.

## Use `@objcMembers`

You could just use `@objcMembers` on the class.

> Applying @objcMembers attribute to a class implicitly adds the @objc attribute to all of its Objective-C compatible members.
>
> [Writing Swift Classes and Protocols with Objective-C Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html)

Keep in mind: *because applying the @objc attribute can increase the compiled size of an app and adversely affect performance, **only apply the @objcMembers attribute on declarations when each member needs to have the @objc attribute applied**.*

## Switch inference to the old behavior

You can also change the project's behavior under:
`Build Settings` > `Swift 3 @objc Inference` > `On`/`Off`

Related questions:

- [The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379348/the-use-of-swift-3-objc-inference-in-swift-4-mode-is-deprecated)
- [How can I deal with @objc inference deprecation with #selector() in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390378/how-can-i-deal-with-objc-inference-deprecation-with-selector-in-swift-4?noredirect=1&lq=1)