# How can I get list of class properties in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

```
func getAllPropertyName(_ aClass : AnyClass) -> [String] {
    var count = UInt32()
    let properties = class_copyPropertyList(aClass, &count)
    var propertyNames = [String]()
    let intCount = Int(count)
    for i in 0 ..< intCount {
        let property : objc_property_t = properties![i]!
        guard let propertyName = NSString(utf8String:   property_getName(property)) as? String else {
            debugPrint("Couldn't unwrap property name for \(property)")
            break
        }
        propertyNames.append(propertyName)
    }
    free(properties)
    return propertyNames
```

This code work till Swift 3.2. But I'm using Swift 4 and it's giving me an empty Array[String].

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44762460/1187415 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/1187415: You explicitly must expose members to the Objective-C runtime with `@objc` in Swift 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of class's properties in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844681/list-of-classs-properties-in-swift)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get `properties like below :

```
class ClassTest {
    var prop1: String?
    var prop2: Bool?
    var prop3: Int?
}

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: ClassTest())
print(mirror.children.flatMap { $0.label }) // ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
extension NSObject {
    func propertyNames() -> [String] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return mirror.children.compactMap{ $0.label }
    }
}
```